# Notifications disappearing fast for Microsoft Teams PWA

Tags: gnome, pop-os, notifications

- Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04
- GNOME Version: 42.5

I have Microsoft Teams installed as a PWA (Originally through Chrome and now, God Forbid, through my distro's Edge-on-Linux, just to test if it was a Chrome issue)

- When I receive messages on Teams, I receive notifications.
- They disappear after a few seconds
- If I click the notification area fast enough, I might see it there for a split second, but it disappears anyway.

This is a problem - my focus might be elsewhere, e.g. on a different screen.

I would like the notifications to stay until I actively clear them.

I have tested various gnome extensions:

- [Permanent Notifications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/)
- [Persistent Notifications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5672/persistent-notifications/)
- [Notifications Alert](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/258/notifications-alert-on-user-menu/)
- [Always Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2594/always-indicator/)
- [Notification Timeout](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3795/notification-timeout/) (Only goes to 10 minutes - what if I'm away from the PC?)
- [Notifications Logger](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4093/notifications-to-file/) (Logs to a file - this one *is* persistent but I'm not gonna build a frankenstein solution on top of that, nor remember to check the file)

And just...

Is there a solution to this? Does the notification system eat them, or is it because Teams sends a "stop notification" message after a short while? Is there a gnome extension that solves this but just doesn't have "notification" in the name?

Comment: as an aside *God Forbid, ... Edge-on-Linux* is FAR better than the crap google dish out :p

Comment: Wouldn't know, I'm a Mozilla user at heart - but the Mozilla PWA user story is *something else*

Comment: well, they dropped PWA many versions ago - never did get it quite right

Comment: I have the same issue, also on Pop!_OS. Never see any notifications, but I can't tell if they disappear quickly of it I don't get them at all. This is a quite new issue, did not have it until a couple of months ago.